# How to find all web services running on my system?

Tags: windows, web-services, rest, service, restful-url

Is there a way to find all the web services running in my system?specifically rest services if possible?I am using windows 7 system 64 bit.

Comment: Provide a succinct definition for a web service, and you have a specification for the program you need to write.

Comment: @IInspectable dont need a program , is there any windows command like netstat ,which could possibly list all web services binding to my IP.

Comment: What is a web service? You need to **succinctly** define, what comprises a web service.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I think you are thinking in two different things...
The first is "services" running on your operating system (Windows 7), and a service could be more than a web service, for example your database or your application server.
The second, a web service is running (when it works fine) through a application server (JBoss, Weblogic, Glassfish), not in a operating system, so if you want to know your web services you must to log in into your application server and search them, or check in the folder of deployments to know about it.